# Why is my many-to-many-through association failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-associations

I have set up a twitter-like following model. Users can all subscribe to each other. I am getting an error in my users controller when trying to create the relationship.

user.rb:

```
has_many :subscriptions
has_many :providers, :through => :subscriptions

has_many :followings, :class_name => "Subscription"
has_many :followers, :through => :followings
```

subscription.rb

```
belongs_to :provider, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => "provider_id"
belongs_to :follower, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => "follower_id"
```

users_controller.rb

```
69 def follow
70   logger.debug params.to_yaml
71   @user = User.find(params["user_id"])
72   logger.debug @user.to_yaml
73   if current_user.providers << @user
74     flash[:notice] = "Subscribed"
75   else
76     flash[:error] = "Unable to subscribe."
77   end
78 end
```

This is the error when I call follow:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: user_id):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:73:in `follow'
```

I have verified that I ran rake db:migrate - the subscription table has two fields provider_id and follower_id. Can anyone help me with the error and explain why it is looking for a 'user_id' attribute?

**Update:**

show.html.erb:

```
<%= button_to "Subscribe", user_follow_path(@user), :remote => true %>
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  resources :locations
  resources :saved_events
  resources :saved_locations
  post "follow"
end
```

rake routes | grep follow:

```
user_follow POST     /users/:user_id/follow(.:format)                    {:action=>"follow", :controller=>"users"}
```

Comment: can you annotate line 73 from users_controller.b in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top) as a guide, I came up with this solution, which fixes the data model so that collection functions work as they should.

Make the provider id accessible and remove the foreign keys in the subscription model.

subscription.rb:

```
attr_accessible :provider_id
belongs_to :provider, :class_name => 'User'
belongs_to :follower, :class_name => 'User'
```

Add foreign keys for subscriptions and reverse_subscriptions in the user model.

user.rb:

```
has_many :subscriptions, :foreign_key => "subscriber_id", :dependent => :destroy
has_many :subscribed_to, :through => :subscriptions, :source => :provider

has_many :reverse_subscriptions, :class_name => "Subscription", :foreign_key => "provider_id", :dependent => :destroy
has_many :followers, :through => :reverse_subscriptions
```

I also added helper methods to the user model.

user.rb:

```
def following?(provider)
  subscriptions.find_by_provider_id(provider)
end

def follow!(provider)
  subscriptions.create!(:provider_id => provider.id)
end

def unfollow!(provider)
  subscriptions.find_by_provider_id(provider).destroy
end
```

Then, in the controller, we can call follow! or unfollow!

user_controller.rb:

```
...
current_user.unfollow!(@user)
...
current_user.follow!(@user)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's giving you a error is because the when you call `<<` on the providers collection the user doesn't know it's supposed to be a follower. So it's basically saying, "I'm a user, add me to this collection of providers!" instead of "This guy is going to follow me, I'm now a provider and he's a follower"

The simplest answer may be to just do

user.rb:

```
def follow(other_user)
  Subscription.create(:provider => other_user, :follower => self)
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
def follow
  @user = User.find(params["user_id"])
  if current_user.follow(@user)
    flash[:notice] = "Subscribed"
  else
    flash[:error] = "Unable to subscribe."
  end
end
```

Comment: I am using devise so I have this before_filter: `before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:update,:follow]`

Comment: Alright, I think I may see whats going on I'll update my answer then.

Comment: Subscription sorry, I edited it again. Also added a link on the reason for `inverse_of`. If that works let me know I don't know how it will work with a self-reference association.

Comment: I did some editing, and did some abstraction for logic sake. But as of Rails 3.1 you can actually manipulate some :through associations as long as the have the `:inverse_of` option set. I think the problem with yours is that it's self-referring. Good Luck though

Comment: There are still issues with the model when using this workaround (find not working for example). I posted a more complete solution that fixes the model.